# Long running task get killed by android OS

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am doing a long task running (decoding bitmaps) suppose it is processing 2000 images and user pressed the home button and do task on other app and when he switched to my app, it gets killed and to tackle that I also show status on notification area but no luck.

Can anyone suggest that my app run in background without getting killed without any service (if possible)

Comment: Please read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/

Comment: It's not possible to do it without using a service. Even a service might get stopped if the operating system needs memory.

Comment: @HB can u guide with sample code or link reference?

Comment: @Amit  I suggest you do not use background service when you load 2000 images, you could make an activity that loading 2000 images in foreground and show this process to users

Answer (score 0):

For a long running task like you're describing I would use the Android JobScheduler Framework:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-job-scheduler

https://blog.xamarin.com/replacing-services-jobs-android-oreo-8-0/

The [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler) will be managed by the Android OS, but still run under your application context.  Also keep in mind of Android's [background execution limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) for Android 8+ and [Doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) battery saving features.  With that being said, if the process runs for too long, Android may decide to kill it anyway.  I would maybe scheduling multiple jobs if your image list is large.

Without knowing more details of your requirements and processing demands it's hard to provide a more robust solution, but using a JobScheuduler would be a good start.

Comment: App is basically resizing images and I am testing to do the job with 2000 images and it got killed. Does job scheduler sufficient for this type of work.

Comment: I also tried manually turnoff the battery optimization but this doesn't have any effect on the app

Comment: As I am showing notification to user with filename with progressbar then why Android treat as a idle app or not doing anything? App is interacting with notification continuously and by clicking on notification it redirect to the running activity (showing whole processing details to user)